How to Handle Clipboard Access Prompts in TestCafe During Automation?
I’m using TestCafe for browser automation, but I’m running into an issue with clipboard access. When I use the navigator.clipboard.readText() method inside a ClientFunction to read clipboard content, I get a prompt in Chrome asking for permission to allow or deny clipboard access.
Since this prompt requires user interaction, it interrupts the automation and causes it to fail. I’ve tried triggering the clipboard interaction after simulating a user click, but the prompt still appears.
Here’s an example of the code I'm using:
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
const getClipboardContent = ClientFunction(async () => {
    const clipboardText = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
    return clipboardText;
});

test('Access Clipboard in TestCafe', async t => {
    // Simulating some actions before reading clipboard
    const element = Selector('#someElement');
    await t.click(element);
    // Get clipboard content (this triggers the prompt in Chrome)
    const clipboardContent = await getClipboardContent();
    console.log(clipboardContent);
});

I need to automate tests that interact with the clipboard without being interrupted by the permission prompt in Chrome. I’m looking for any workaround or solution that allows clipboard access without requiring manual intervention.
Any help or insights would be appreciated!
